# How to show view in a child page, using Ionize CMS?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Ionize CMS to build a project.

This is my page structure:

-- Page 1

----  Page 1.1

------  Page 1.1.1

----------  Article 1.1.1.1

------  Article 1.1.1

------  Article 1.1.2

However when I click on Page 1.1.1, for some reason the theme doesnt show and all I get is the default page.php

When I click page 1.1 everything is fine, problem is with child page inside child page. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

I checked the core file in application/libraries/tagmanager/page.php and changed the method _get_page_view() to do not show the default page in case it doesn't find a 'view'. This is the error I'm now getting:

An Error Was Encountered

Theme error : File "views/" can't be found.

Whiche makes me figure that for some reason it is not recognizing the view I chose in the child's child page.

I know I should ask this at Ionize forum, but the site seems a little dead and nobody answers any question. If someone here uses this CMS I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Show me your code ?  what are your using to load child pages?

Comment: I created them from the admin area, and child pages display using tree_navigation with depth of 4. Then, on the admin area, I choose a 'view' for each child page, but it appears to not recognize it when it is deeper than a level. 
Which code would you like to see?

Comment: Oh ok its cms. You taged it as codeigniter?

Comment: I couldn't create a tag for ionize CMS, sorry :( That's why I put it in question title. Ionize uses Codeigniter, that's why I tag it.

Comment: just i check ionize cms.May be they support 1 level only. If you want further you change code internally not from admin side.

Comment: yes I'm just a bit lost as of where to find that, but i'll keep looking. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Every page has unique view settings in Ionize, they are not getting the closes parent page settings, by default you should set your own view in the child pages too. If you changed the code then add the changed code to your question, because we cannot help without the actual code.

And you can ask in the forum or open a ticket on github (https://github.com/ionize/ionize).

I answering the questions in forum day after day and me and other developers at partikule not checking often the stackoverflow :)